# when does WebViewClient's methods get called?

Tags: android, webview, webviewclient

I have a webview in my app, first it loads a.html, click a button inside a.html then b.html will be loaded,  click a button inside b.html then an activity will be started. In short, the order is **a.html->b.html->starts an activity**. my webView has extended WebViewClient, and override its methods as follow.

```
private class WebViewHandler extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) 
        {
            Log.d("onPageStarted", "onPageStarted:" + url );
            mProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) 
        {
            Log.d("onPageFinished", "onPageFinished:" + url );
            mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
        {
            Log.d("url", "onPageoverloaded the url: "+url);
            String tutorialId = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("=") + 1);
            MetaioDebug.log("Tutorial Id detected: "+tutorialId);
            if (url.startsWith("metaio://"))
            {
                if (tutorialId != null)
                {
                    MetaioDebug.log("Native code tutorial to be loaded #"+tutorialId);
                    if (tutorialId.equals("1"))
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Tutorial1.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }

                return true;
            }
    }
```

problem is that `onPageStarted()` is only called when a.html starts loading but won't be called when b.html starts loading.  `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)` is only called when I click the button in b.html but not in a.html.

I m very confused when should those 3 methods been called?

Answer (score 0):

I think `onPageFinished()` should probably return `false`.

From the [documentation for shouldOverrideUrlLoading ()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29):

`If WebViewClient is provided, return true means the host application handles the url, while return false means the current WebView handles the url.`

Don't know why it doesn't work on `a.html`, but it could be related to your return value since the system will at some point determine if it will handle things itself moving forward.

As for your `onPageStarted` problem, I think you are seeing the expected behavior. [Documentation for onPageStarted():](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageStarted%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String,%20android.graphics.Bitmap%29)

`Notify the host application that a page has started loading. This method is called once for each main frame load so a page with iframes or framesets will call onPageStarted one time for the main frame. This also means that onPageStarted will not be called when the contents of an embedded frame changes, i.e. clicking a link whose target is an iframe.`

I think your WebView considers itself as in a "finished" state since it has already completed the original rendering you already asked it to do from a.html.

A work-around could be creating and inflating a new WebView with b.html to guarantee `onPageFinished()` gets called. I think it depends on how you are loading b.html into the webview.

Do you imply that you ARE seeing `onPageFinished()` called after you load `b.html`, just not `onPageStarted()`? Or do neither get called?

**Added based on comments:**

Try loading `b.html` another way to so that the WebView understands it is loading a totally new resource:

Have the `href` whose current value is `b.html` lead to a JavaScript method that calls back to a JavaScript interface object that calls something like this in Java:

`webview.loadURL("file:///b.html"); //or whatever the file location of b.html is.`

I think this will let your WebView think that it is loading a new resource and so call both `onPageStarted()` and `onPageFinished()`.

Comment: for the last question: yes,onPageFinished() is called after I load b.html, but onPageStarted() is not called when b.html starts loading. the order should be onPageStarted()->onPageFinished(), but thats just not what is happening here.

Comment: `onPageFinished()`doesn't have the same comment as `onPageStarted()` that it is only called once. To me that suggests that it would get called every time you are (re)loading a resource. As unfortunate as it is, I think you are seeing the expected behavior. Btw, how are you loading `b.html`? And is it the same method as for `a.html`?

Comment: what do you mean by "onPageFinished()doesn't have the same comment as onPageStarted()" ?? in a.html there is such line `<a href="b.html">` when it loaded b.html

Comment: Sorry for being vague... I meant that in the Android documentation comments. Check out this url (can't make a link work in comments). "http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageFinished(android.webkit.WebView, java.lang.String)"